# node-mysql2 using conn.release() vs conn.end()

Tags: node.js

Looking at Async/Await example here :

```
https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2/blob/master/documentation/Promise-Wrapper.md
```

the author uses **`c.end()`**

```
   let mysql = require('mysql2/promise');
   let pool = mysql.createPool({database: test});
   // execute in parallel, next console.log in 3 seconds
   await Promise.all([pool.query('select sleep(2)'), pool.query('select sleep(3)')]);
   console.log('3 seconds after');
   await pool.end();
   await conn.end();
```

However, just a few lines above, he uses  **conn.release()**

```
pool.getConnection()
     .then((conn) => {
       var res = conn.query('select foo from bar');
       conn.release();
       return res;
     })
```

What is to be used once we are done using the connection object ?

should it be conn.release() or conn.end() ?

Answer (score 10):

Those examples aren't meant to be doing the same thing. And also, the first example (in your code) references a variable (`conn`) that it never uses. I think that's just a mistake in the example code.

The first example shows how to create a pool, run two concurrent queries (using the pool), wait for all queries to finish, and then clean up. Like I said before, `conn.end()` just doesn't make sense there.

The second example shows you how to request a free connection from the pool, use that connection to run a query (represented by the promise `res`), return the connection to the pool (by calling `conn.release()`), then propagate the result down the promise chain.

The second example can be rewritten to this:

```
let conn = await pool.getConnection();
let res  = conn.query('select foo from bar');

conn.release();

let result = await res;
```

So, `conn.release()` is used to release a connection back to the connection pool. It doesn't close the connection, it merely makes it available to be used for other queries.

`conn.end()` (I assume) closes the connection, and I guess you should only call it when you explicitly created the connection yourself (unlike connections retrieved from the pool, which should be *managed* by the pool).

Comment: great explanation / diferentiation